# How to display distinct list of column values from OData?

Tags: sapui5

I have an OData model with a property column 'category'. In twenty rows are i. e. 3 different categories. Now I want to display a list of all different categories to use as filter for a table. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I started to answer this earlier today but then didnt complete it as it may not be a full answer but this certainly is a good place to start...

Two options I guess: get a function import that just returns a set of the categories and push the problem to the server.

Or process on the client side by using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the column in question.

The best way to do that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15868720/2434654).

So adapting that answer:

```js
var categories = ["SAPUI5","OpenUI5","JavaScript","NodeJS","SAP HANA","JavaScript","SAPUI5"];

var uniq = categories.reduce(function (a,b) {
    if (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ) a.push(b);
    return a;
  }, []);

console.log(uniq); // ["SAPUI5", "OpenUI5", "JavaScript", "NodeJS", "SAP HANA"]
```

Comment: Thanks for adding highlighting @hirse. 
Wonding why this got down voted though ... any care to put up a better answer?